# How can I fix this npm error? npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.19042

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I had no errors when I downgraded to npm@3.10.10 I got this error that keeps showing every time I use npm to update it self or to install anything new, What can I do?

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\usr\\local\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "-g" "npm@latest"
npm ERR! node v14.17.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\Documents\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Hi @Mbistami. Have you ever resolved this problem? I am getting exactly the same issue as you had on a brand new Windows 10 machine. The suggestions below haven't helped me. Thanks.

Comment: I deleted npm and node and reinstalled with LTS also cleaned everything about npm and it worked...

Comment: Thank you Mbistami for answer! Unfortunately this approach doesn't help in my case: I'm using legacy node version (6.10.3) with handling by nvm-windows.

Comment: @InaFK try to change the node version either downgrade or upgrade also verify the npm versions if they are fine or not and hopefully it will help... Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
Follow this directory
C:\Users(your username)\AppData\Roaming
Delete the npm folder and if there is one npm cache folder.
Run npm clean cache —force ( — force is now required to clean cache)
You should be good now if not do option 2.

Option 2:
Follow this directory
C:\Users(your username)\AppData\Roaming
Delete the npm folder and if there is one mom cache folder.
Run npm clean cache —force ( — force is now required to clean cache)
Make sure everything to do with Nodejs is deleted and uninstalled.
Reinstall Nodejs.
You should be good now.
https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2874

Comment: try upgrading/downgrading npm version?