# npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.19044 while installing library using npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, error-handling, compiler-errors

I am working on a project in our organization. while i am trying to run or install libraries it's getting an error.

```
E:\GIT\bookshelf>npm install
npm WARN deprecated bcrypt-nodejs@0.0.3: bcrypt-nodejs is no longer actively maintained. Please use bcrypt or bcryptjs
npm WARN deprecated @angular/http@4.1.3: Package no longer supported. Use @angular/common instead
npm WARN deprecated formidable@1.1.1: Please upgrade to latest, formidable@v2 or formidable@v3!
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.4.1: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated angular-tree-component@3.2.3: Library moved to @circlon/angular-tree-component
npm WARN deprecated multer@1.2.0: Multer 1.x is affected by CVE-2022-24434. This is fixed in v1.4.4-lts.1 which drops support for versions of Node.js before 6. Please upgrade to at least Node.js 6 and version 1.4.4-lts.1 of Multer. If you need support for older versions of Node.js, we are open to accepting patches that would fix the CVE on the main 1.x release line, whilst maintaining compatibility with Node.js 0.10.
npm WARN deprecated angular2-infinite-scroll@0.3.4: Please use the new --> ngx-infinite-scroll <--- supports in Angular +4, AOT compilation and optimized code bundle
npm WARN deprecated log4js@2.3.12: 2.x is no longer supported. Please upgrade to 6.x or higher.
npm WARN deprecated ckeditor@4.5.9: We have renamed the @ckeditor package. New versions are available under the @ckeditor4 name.
npm WARN deprecated angular2-recaptcha@0.6.0: Package no longer supported.
npm WARN deprecated fingerprintjs2@1.5.1: Package has been renamed to @fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs. Install @fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs to get updates.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.83.0: request has been deprecated
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.17.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! Cannot convert undefined or null to object
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm WARN deprecated ng2-bootstrap@1.4.0: ng2-bootstrap is renamed to ngx-bootstrap, please do npm i ngx-bootstrap -S
npm WARN deprecated request-promise@4.2.2: request-promise has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package,

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     E:\GIT\bookshelf\npm-debug.log
```

I am using node version: 6.17.1 ( setup via NVM )
npm version: 3.10.10
windows machine.
Anyone helps me to find out what am I missing?

Comment: Everything is deprecated. Why do you use such old versions?

Comment: Did you try to remove the `package-json.lock` file and run `npm install` again?

Comment: @DreamBold I tried but problem doesn't resolve

Comment: What error do you see in the console? Is it the same as before?

Answer (score 0):

first remove package-json.lock file then try this npm command:

```
npm install --no-audit
```

run the command on your terminal.
or you can read this [How can I fix this npm error? npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.19042](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68061008/how-can-i-fix-this-npm-error-npm-err-windows-nt-10-0-19042), similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and installing the Nodejs 32-bit solved it

Answer (score 0):

The versions of Node.js and npm you're using are quite outdated.

your error is  **Cannot convert undefined or null to object**, which can be a result of one or more of the deprecated/older modules or the older versions of Node.js/npm being incompatible with them.

try to use

```
nvm install 16
nvm use 16
and try to clear your cache
npm cache clean -f
```

or if you can remove node_modules and package-lock,json file

last reinstall `npm install`

hope it will help you